# Delete app folder (with Shared Preferences and downloaded images)

Tags: java, android, bitmap, sharedpreferences, logout

In my app i've got 5 accounts. User can use button 'logout', than he can enter password and log in to another account.
So my question:
How can i delete ALL Shared preferences (**INTERNAL** storage) (there are a lot of them - about 110-120 files) and all pictures (about 10)?

I'm trying to use this code to delete Shared Preferences:

```
 File sharedPreferenceFile = new File("/data/data/"+ getPackageName()+ "/shared_prefs/");
 File[] listFiles = sharedPreferenceFile.listFiles();
 for (File file : listFiles) {
 file.delete();}
```

But i can't do this because **Result of 'File.delete()' is ignored**

There how i put value of Shared Preferences (if it's needed):

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("timeTable", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor sedt2 = sp2.edit();
sedt2.putString("timeTable", place1.getText().toString());
sedt2.apply();
```

And there is how i put images and bitmap to app directory:

```
 bitmap_backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
 ContextWrapper cw1 = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
 File directory = cw1.getDir("backgroundimage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 if (!directory.exists()) {
 directory.mkdir();}
 File mypath1 = new File(directory, "backgroundimage.png");
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath1);
 bitmap_backgroundImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
 fos.close();
```

Is there any code, that can delete pictures and shared preferences on button click?

Answer (score 0):

To Clear SharedPerferences you have to write

```
sp.edit().clear().commit()
```

To delete images stored in file system

```
for(File file: dir.listFiles()) {
     file.delete();
}
```

Comment: thank you for advice! This code will delete ALL shared preferences in directory or only SP with name "sp"? I'have a lot of shared preferences with different names, so it will be very difficult to delete them all by name.  And about files: this code can delete all files in directory or not? Thank you for responce.

Comment: yes this code will delete all shared preference. Here sp is the object of Shared Preferences. And also second code will delete all files in that folder